# Cómo inserto datos correctamente en un array tipo JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

El problema está en que estoy intentando ingresar los datos de personas en un array JSON desde JavaScript pero cuando ingreso una persona y sus datos, se reemplazan los datos de esa persona en todas las posiciones del vector, 
ej: ingreso a David Pérez

1. David Pérez

Luego ingreso a Juan Navarro y el array queda así

1. Juan Navarro
2. Juan Navarro

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
var personas = []
let persona = {
  nombre : null,
  apellido: null,
  edad : 0,
  sexo : null,
  pulsaciones : 0,
}

//recibo los datos desde el HTML y los guardo en el array

function recibirValoresPersona(){   
  if(ValidarDatos()  == "ok"){    
    persona.nombre = document.getElementById("Nombre").value
    persona.sexo = CalcularSexo( document.getElementsByName("sexo") )
    persona.edad = document.getElementById("Edad").value    
    persona.apellido = document.getElementById("Apellido").value
    persona.pulsaciones = Pulsaciones()     
  }
  personas.push(persona)
  return personas
}

//convierto el array a JSON y los guardo en el localStorage

var Guardar = function (){    
  if(ValidarDatos() == "ok"){
    personas =  recibirValoresPersona();
    localStorage.setItem("personas",JSON.stringify(personas))
    alert("Datos guardados")
  } else alert(ValidarDatos())   
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que el array no guarda una copia literal de los valores del objeto, sino una **referencia**, y estás utilizando el mismo objeto cada vez (es decir, sólo existe un objeto, lo que tienes son 2 referencias en el array a él), por lo tanto sólo tienes los últimos valores.
Crea un objeto nuevo para almacenar en el array, por ejemplo modificando tu código así:

```
function recibirValoresPersona(){   
  if(ValidarDatos()  == "ok"){    
    persona.nombre = document.getElementById("Nombre").value
    persona.sexo = CalcularSexo( document.getElementsByName("sexo") )
    persona.edad = document.getElementById("Edad").value    
    persona.apellido = document.getElementById("Apellido").value
    persona.pulsaciones = Pulsaciones()     
  }
  personas.push({...persona});
  return personas
}
```

> {...persona}

crea una copia del objeto persona, y es el que se almacenará en el array.